# How to make the scrollbar width / height responsive / percentage?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, responsive, percentage

I'm working with Twine, and I have everything about the scrollbar styled as I want except I need to make the horizontal scrollbar height responsive.
According to this article you can set it as percentage: https://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/
But whenever I set the scrollbar height to a percentage it disappears completely.
To check if it was Twine or something, I went to a website on the Brave browser and set the scrollbar width to a percentage and it disappeared. I went to a different site on Chrome and did the same thing and the scrollbar disappeared.
I just added this element:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 18%;}
```

It's looking like in order to make this one thing responsive I'll have to build a scrollbar from scratch and use JavaScript. I found this article for making a basic scrollbar, but didn't know enough JavaScript to make it horizontal (I basically don't know any JavaScript).
https://htmldom.dev/create-a-custom-scrollbar/

If there is a similar example to the above for making a horizontal scrollbar with JavaScript, or a way to make a scrollbar width / height responsive with CSS or JavaScript or something, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Can you share your code or snippet on codepen/jsfiddle?

Comment: There isn't really anything to add more than what I did:
```body::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 18%;}```
You can add this to any site with a vertical scrollbar to replicate the problem.

Comment: kinda weird but px, % or vh/vw vanish the scrollbar :P .... that's why I was asking for code coz this single statement is vanishing the scrollbar

Comment: Maybe you're on Firefox, I think it only allows ```scrollbar-width: thin;``` and so on. Making your own scrollbar with JavaScript is I think the only way to really customise the scrollbar on Firefox.

Comment: no. I am using chrome

Comment: Here's a screencast of the test: I also changed the background of the thumb to white, because apparently on that site it became transparent when I changed the width: perhaps that's what happened to yours. https://www.loom.com/share/68084b967c434950b2bd77440a46ab94

Comment: Hey, thanks... yes!! does make it transparent, and have to explicitly add color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 0.8vw;}
```

As `%`, the `vw` is a relative width unit. This unit is based on the **width of the viewport**. A value of 1vw is equal to 1% of the viewport width. For example, if the viewport is 50cm wide, 1vw is equal to 0.5cm.

Let me know if that helps. If yes, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: It helps! 
The scrollbar accepts it, though basing it on vh causes some (hopefully minor) problems on a mobile. I think the problem still needs to be addressed that percentages can't be used anymore, and in a way that suggests a glitch of some kind. Using vh will work acceptably for me, but others would still need JavaScript solutions.

Comment: Incidentally, inspired by your answer, I also tried aspect-ratio, which works for another thing in the project. While the scrollbar didn't disappear, it ignored the aspect-ratio and went to default height.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :) I used percentage in the past for long time but I started using vw and vh some time ago, because it works in your case (customizing the scrollbar) and it also works in some other cases (e.g. changing Bootstrap's width and height where percentage doesn't work but vw and vh does).